# Can someone explain the EASA approval process to fly ETOPS?

Tags: easa, etops

First of all does the TC holder (manufacturer) of a new aircraft have to gain approval to state that the aircraft is capable of flying etops to a certain level..? I.e ETOPS 120.

Secondly does the operator have to then show compliance to show they are maintaining the aircraft for ETOPS operation to gain certification within their AOC?

So can you have an aircraft for example that is ETOPS capable (from manufacture) but not ETOPS certified if airline aren't maintaining to required standard or have approval from NAA?

Basically I don't understand who has to get the approval, TC holder, operator or both from EASA or the local NAA?

It someone can clarify that would be fantastic..

Comment: Related: [Can any aircraft have ETOPS?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/45962/3201) (not a duplicate). Also a summarized [ETOPS approbation process](https://www.ecologique-solidaire.gouv.fr/sites/default/files/Guide_d_approbation_ETOPS_Ed1_V0_mars_16.pdf), but in French. It references [this long EASA document](https://www.easa.europa.eu/sites/default/files/dfu/Annex%20II%20-%20AMC%2020-6.pdf).